# how to operate Dynamically Creating dropdown Controls in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have created dynamically 5 Dropdown List. It is from aspx.cs

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();
                drop.ID = "dropdownlist" + i;
                form1.Controls.Add(drop);
                form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
             }
```

I already have another dropdown code like

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM RejectedProduct"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Item for adding", "0"));}
```

How I can use this code for dynamically Creating new 5 dropdown each?

Comment: using dynamic controls is a bad idea in asp.net as the controls get destroyed on each postback and have to be recreated. they will not hold the value you put in them. its a bad idea to do so.

Comment: Dynamically created control needs few steps; you are missing a lot of steps. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18155057/296861) answer. If you have specific question, please come back and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out comments of Mysterio11 & Win.

The basic idea of filling data is below. Most importantly it's not optimized. Creating command and connection in a loop is vary bad idea.

```
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList DropDownList1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)FindControl("dropdownlist" + i);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM RejectedProduct"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
                        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Item for adding", "0"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: It throws an exception
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @joyoares I am really sorry about the delay. The code I used to test is attached to this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_czp2rbfZFjbURncGljZk53X2s) and its working fine. Please go through it.